# Elixir Mocking: Assign a module to a module attribute

Tags: elixir

For testing I want to make a mock, as described by José Valim [here](http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2015/10/mocks-and-explicit-contracts/)

But I keep getting a "CaseClauseError" error. I made a simple project [here](https://github.com/micahrye/oddities) if interested.

When using Application.get_env to to bind a module to a module attribute, e.g.

```
defmodule Att do
  @file Application.get_env(:att, :file_module)

  def hello do
    file = Application.get_env(:att, :file_module)
    file.hello()
    # @file.hello
  end
end
```

It results in the following compile error:

```
mix compile
    == Compilation error in file lib/att.ex ==
** (CaseClauseError) no case clause matching: [{:file, Att.Real, false, 2}]
    lib/att.ex:5: (module)
    (stdlib) erl_eval.erl:670: :erl_eval.do_apply/6
```

If I comment out `@file Application.get_env(:att, :file_module)` there is no problem and the use of file = Application.get_env(:att, :file_module) in the hello function is fine.

The problem is not `Application.get_env` specific as if do the following

```
defmodule Att do
  # @file Application.get_env(:att, :file_module)
  @file_mock Att.Mock

  def hello do
    file = Application.get_env(:att, :file_module)
    file.hello()
    Att.Mock.hello()
    # @file.hello
  end
end
```

Then `@file_mock Att.Mock` results in the same CaseClauseError. The problem seems to be assigning a module to a module attribute.

Comment: Which line exactly throws that error? The problem is not assigning a module to a module attribute. You can definitely do that. The error message says line 17 but your code is only 8 lines.

Comment: Sorry, that might have been before deleting some lines, edited with new error msg. As you can see it is complaining of line 5 `def hello do`, but if I comment out line 2 `@file Application.get_env(:att, :file_module)` all is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@file` is a special module attribute which stores file name to use in stacktraces. If you instead assign it to another name, it should work fine.

> **@file**
>
> Changes the filename used in stacktraces for the function or macro
>   that follows the attribute, such as:
>
> ```
> defmodule MyModule do
>   @doc "Hello world"
>   @file "hello.ex"
>   def hello do
>     "world"
>   end
> end
> ```

<sup>[Source](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Module.html#module-file)</sup>

Comment: Good catch. I will improve the error message in this case. :)

Comment: Awesome that my baffle caught José attention, thanks Dogbert and José.

Comment: Docs for GenServer list reserved attributes, [here](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Module.html)

Comment: José, nice error messaging might include if you name a attribute wrong, such as using a  leading capital letter for the attribute name. I don't recall seeing naming rules for attributes in the docs.